# How to play an uploaded video in django rest framework

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have a trouble with using django-rest-framework.
I uploaded some videos.
And I try to play that videos in react.
But I faced 404 error.
I added static and media root in setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

This is upload code.

```
        videofile = request.FILES['videoData']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(videofile.name, videofile)
        user = request.user
        File.objects.create(
            user = user,
            title = request.data['videotitle'],
            url = filename,
            categorys = request.data['categories'],
            preveimage = request.data['vidoePrevimg'],
            filetype = request.data['videoType'],
            filesize = request.data['videoSize']
        )
```

It works fine

And in react I tried like this.

```
<ReactPlayer url={`${baseurl}/media/${videoDetaildata.url}`} playing={true} controls={true} playIcon={true}/>
```

This works when the url is Youtube url.
Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During development you have also to append media url and static url to the urlpatterns.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Kindly check the following [Serving files uploaded by a user during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).
Make sure not to use the above example in production, check the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/vitorfs/0a889e491085f6044bc328ae300b3d19).